# How can I get the maximum integer value in Cython?

Tags: python, integer, cython

I'm using Cython to optimize a library. There's a part in the code where it looks for something with minimum cost. The original code looked a bit like this:

```
cost = float('inf')
for thing in things:
    thing_cost = do_stuff(thing)
    if thing_cost < cost:
        cost = thing_cost
```

Except for the initial value these costs are all positive integers, so I'd like to make cost an `unsigned int`. Is there something like `MAX_INT` defined somewhere that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the same thing you'd use in C, `limits.h`.

```
# something.pxd
cdef extern from "limits.h":
    cdef int INT_MAX
    cdef unsigned int UINT_MAX
```

The values can then be used in Cython.